# What version of Python should i install for emscripten compiler?

Tags: python, version, emscripten

I want to install Python as the requirements for `Emscripten copiler`.
I want to know if any version is ok for this, because i found an old site with instuctions but there is said to install Python 2.7.12 or newer.
I found a Python 3.7.0 version from 2018 and i don't know if this version should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3.6 will be great. It will definitely work, but yeah be careful while setting the path.

Comment: What problems sould i found?

Comment: check this link it will help you alot.... 
   https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/4818